# ¿Es correcto "siempre quieren y terminan sometiendo"?

Tags: verbos, gramática

Encuentro en una novela que estoy leyendo el siguiente texto:

> De entre todas las manías, sin duda la más habitual es hacer el amor
>   por las mañanas. A esa hora los hombres siempre quieren y terminan
>   sometiendo a las mujeres.

¿Es aceptable la construcción “siempre quieren y terminan sometiendo”?

¿Se supone que en “siempre quieren” está elíptico el infinitivo “someter”, de forma que “siempre quieren someter” se ha reducido a “siempre quieren”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Me parece que el autor quiere decir otra cosa distinta a lo que entiendes. Creo que el autor intenta decir esto:

> A esa hora los hombres siempre quieren (hacer el
>   amor) y (ellos, los hombres) terminan sometiendo a las mujeres.

Así, sí tiene sentido :)